# using python3.10 with venv, script failure: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python

I'd like to use python3.10 for match pattern feature.
I was previously using python3.8 on ubuntu20.04 with wsl2 without issue.

When using python3.10, a script importing from google.cloud fails

To install python3.10, I did:
adding sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.10

I installed venv:
python3.10 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate

and once activated , I ran python3.10 -m pip install google.cloud
and also python3.10 -m pip install google

Installation of google.cloud semt ok
Nevertheless when I run once venv activated the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.10
from google.cloud import bigquery
# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()
```

I get the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ced/bigquery-gcloud/./survival_frequency", line 2, in 
from google.cloud import bigquery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Thanks for your help

Comment: How did you execute the script ? With interpreter given or relying on the shebang ?

Comment: I execute it with interpreter (shebang indicating python version #/usr/bin/python3.10 )

Answer (score 1):

actually, looking directly in env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google_cloud-0.34.0.dist-info/METADATA, it is said that this package doesn't install anything after june 2018 and that it is necessary to get packages directly from other sources. On pypi, the google.cloud package supports python version <=3.9. I guess I'll have to wait till google.cloud gets some support for python3.10